# What is prevent my validation function not to run when the form is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

What exactly is happening to the form that is not passing the function? I am attempting to validate that the form is not empty by using this function:

JS:

```
function validateForm() {
    console.log("Validate");
    var y = document.forms["form"]["itemEntered"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Must enter an item");
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
      <div id="center-container">
        <h4>Enter an Item for Your Shopping List:</h4>
        <hr />
        <form name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
          <label for="item">Item:</label> 
          <input required type="text" placeholder="Shopping Items" id="item" name="itemEntered" autocomplete="off" />
          <input type="button"  value="Enter" id="Enter" onclick="javascript:addItem();" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Project running in Code Pen http://cdpn.io/JGCDB

You can see that even if the field is empty it still display on the list.

I also tried using the required attribute in the form tag, but didn't work.

Comment: When I try your code in Chrome it tells me I have to fill in the field, that's coming from the `required` attribute.

Comment: I also see `Validate` in the console.

Comment: Note that the value of a form control is a string, so `y == null` will never be true (removing it won't fix your problem, it will just remove some useless code).

Comment: @Barmar i am also running chrome but it does make it required.

Comment: @Barmar I don't see it in the console either.

Comment: I don't know why. I click on the field and then press Return, and I see `Validate` in the console.

Comment: @Barmar i see what you mean when you press the return key, but what about when you press the enter button? right next to the text field.

Comment: The Enter button is used to add an item to the form, not submit it. Why would you expect it to run the `onsubmit` action?

Comment: I was going based on a w3schools tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few issues with your code, first of all onclick will execute before the validation, secondly you have declared your input as "button" rather than "submit", hence the click will not trigger the form submit event. Below is the corrected code, hope it helps.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function validateForm() {
    console.log("Validate");
    var y = document.forms["form"]["itemEntered"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Must enter an item");
        return false;
    }

    alert('passed validation...');
    addItem();
    return true;
}

function addItem() {
   alert('adding item...');
}
</script>
```

And here's the markup.

```
<div>
      <div id="center-container">
        <h4>Enter an Item for Your Shopping List:</h4>
        <hr />
        <form name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
          <label for="item">Item:</label> 
          <input required type="text" placeholder="Shopping Items" id="item" name="itemEntered" autocomplete="off" />
          <input type="submit" value="Enter" id="Enter" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This has solved my problem. However, it has caused another, when I run it in a browser. The page seems to refresh and the text disappears. It does not happen in Code Pen. any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to do my best guess is that you're actually not using the form post at all, and that you just want the validation to run on submit (or button click) if that's the case I can think of two quick ways of solving it. One is to remove the onsubmit attribute from the form then return the input to be a button and with the onclick event of the button calling the validateForm() function. Second approach is to leave the code as it is and return false after calling the addItem() function, this will prevent the form submission and the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return true if the validation is correct

```
function validateForm() {
    console.log("Validate");
    var y = document.forms["form"]["itemEntered"].value;
    if (y == "") {
        alert("Must enter an item");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No you don't. If the function returns anything other than `false`, the default action is performed. This is a strict comparison, so `undefined` doesn't match.

Comment: The function is called when you submit the form but you are not using a submit button.
Try to add if(validateForm()) before adding an element in your addItem function